# how many ways of distributing marbles

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Looking through my old statistic books and came upon a very simple question, but I can't just remember the solution.

5 Red Marbles and 5 Blue Marbles. 10 People. How many ways can these marbles be distributed?

the first person has a choice of either red or blue, so it'd be (10C5 or 10C5. The second person either has 5 blue 4 red to choose from or 4 red 5 blue to choose from...and im confused.

How do i solve this? I feel like it's 5! * 5! but not sure..

Comment: **Question:** Does everyone get exactly one marble?  If so just choose 5 of the 10 people to get a red marble and give everyone else a blue marble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the people be indexed as $1,2,\dots,10$. If you would have 10 marbles of 10 different colors, the number of variants would be $10!$ since the first selects from 10, the second from 9, etc.

If you assume that $5!$ of these colors are red and all red marbles are equivalent, you have to divide the number of variants by $5!$ since their order is ignored. Similarly for blue marbles. Thus, the number of possible assignments is
$$
\frac{10!}{5!5!} =252
$$